# What is the significance of strictly convex?

Tags: calculus, functions, information-theory

I am learning the definition of convex (in a book on information theory). The book says that that if equality holds only when $λ$ is 0 or 1 then the function is "strictly" convex.

$$
    f(\lambda x+(1−\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x)+(1−\lambda)f(y)
$$

I have a good [Intuition behind convex functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280585/intuition-behind-convex-functions). But I don't understand the significance behind "strict" convexity. I understand how linear functions could be convex and how, for a linear function, the equality would hold when $λ$ has any value. Is "strict" convexity meant to exclude such cases? This question seems to get to the same problem but does not answer my question: [Visual difference between strictly concave and not strictly concave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376690/visual-difference-between-strictly-concave-and-not-strictly-concave)

Answer (score 1):

This condition means that no three distinct points on the function can be co-linear.